# Проблема с jquery

Tags: jquery

Вот код:

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    id="'" + "#" + $(this).val() + "'";
    kolichestvo=$(id).val();
    alert(kolichestvo);

<input type="text" id="<?=data['id']?>" value="<?=data['value']?>">
<button value="<?=data['id']?>" class="plus">
```

Не срабатывает, id получаем нормально, а вот получить val() элемента с этим id  не получается. id и value целые числа. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
    id=$(this).val();
    kolichestvo=$("#"+id).val();
    alert(kolichestvo);
});
```

Comment: Spasibo, pomoglo

Answer (score 3):

Зачем Вы окружили ID апострофами? Например

```
val = 'someval'
```

тогда

```
id="'" + "#" + $(this).val() + "'";
```

равно

```
'#someval'
```

что является неверным селектором.
Апострофы не нужны.

```
id = "#" + $(this).val();
```

Comment: Spasibo, pomoglo